# Deploy SharePoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to deploy SharePoint Hosted App in an **On Premise Environment** I have created the App.

Can anyone provide the detailed step how to deploy SharePoint Hosted App On Premise Environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to publish the app to the local App Catalog. The App Catalog is managed in the Apps section of Central Administration. Go to Central Admin -> Apps -> Manage App Catalog.

If an App Catalog has not been created you will be able to create one.

[image: App Catalog 1]

If the App catalog has already been created you can access it through the link provided.

[image: App catalog 2]

NOTE: There is one App Catalog per Web Application so, if you have multiple Web Applications, make sure the correct one is shown in the top-right of the page.

In Visual Studio, right-click your project and select Publish. When the **Publish your app** page appears, click **Package the app** to create an App Package.

[image: Publish your app]

A Windows Explorer window will open to the folder containing your App Package (the file will have an app extension).

Navigate to the App Catalog and click **Apps for SharePoint** in the Quick Launch Bar (on the left).

Click new document and select your App Package.

[image: New document]

Add details about the app in the dialog that pops up and then click Save.

[image: App details]

You app is now in your local App Catalog.

Now go to any site in the target Web Application, and then go to Site Contents -> Add an app -> From Your Organization. Your app will be there to add.